# Simple Button with ability for user to enter the amount on my site

Tags: payment

I am new to payPal. I'd like to use a simple PayNow button on my site. The problem is that I would like my webUsers to enter any amount they want to pay on my site and have it transfer to payPal when the Pay button is clicked.

This option does not seem to be available in any of the button types. They require preset amounts or entering the amount on the PP site. Is my only option to dive into learning the API?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you need:

```html
    <form name="input" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR BUSINESS NAME">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ITEM NAME">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="ITEM ID NUMBER">
    Other amount: €<input type="text" maxlength="200" style="width:50px;" name="amount" value="5.00"> EUR<br />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    </form>
```

Change the value of the variable `business` to the receiver email, i.e.:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="receiver@email.com">
```

---

You may want to read [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard - PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)